# Something wrong with my IF statement

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, database, if-statement

I created a simple code for my web game, there are no errors but some part of the code does not work. Parts which do not work are last two if statements, it won't give users an Antimatter, but it prints out correct message. Why it won't update DB correctly ?

CODE:

```
    ///////////////////////////////BLACKBOX////////////////
function buyblackbox(){
global $USER, $PLANET, $LNG, $UNI, $CONF,$resource,$pricelist;
$blackbox = HTTP::_GP('blackbox', 0);
$price = 10000 * $blackbox;
$loli   = mt_rand(1,2);
if ($price < 0) {
$this->printMessage("Hack attempt.", true, array('game.php?page=premium', 2));
}
if($USER['antimatter'] < $price){
$this->printMessage("You do not have enough antimatter", true, array('game.php?page=premium', 2));
die();
}
elseif($blackbox < 0){
$this->printMessage("Hack attempt.", true, array('game.php?page=premium', 2));
die();
}else{
    $USER['antimatter'] -= $price;
$GLOBALS['DATABASE']->query("UPDATE ".USERS." SET `darkbox` = '".$loli."', `antimatter` = `antimatter` - '".$price."' WHERE `id` = ".$USER['id'].";");

if($USER['darkbox'] == 1)
{
$GLOBALS['DATABASE']->query("UPDATE ".USERS." SET `darkmatter` = `darkmatter` - '".$price."' WHERE `id` = ".$USER['id'].";");
$this->printMessage('vins nem sit has succesfully be bought', true, array('game.php?page=premium', 2));
}
if($USER['darkbox'] == 2)
{
$GLOBALS['DATABASE']->query("UPDATE ".USERS." SET `darkmatter` = `darkmatter` + '".$price."' WHERE `id` = ".$USER['id'].";");
$this->printMessage('BlackBox has succesfully be bought', true, array('game.php?page=premium', 2));
}
}
die();
}
/////////////////////////////////END BLACKBOX///////////////////////
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change your DB query so the calculation for remaining antimatter is done in code, rather than as part of the SQL query ...

```
$GLOBALS['DATABASE']->query("UPDATE ".USERS." SET `darkmatter` = ". ($USER['antimatter'] - $price) ." WHERE `id` = ".$USER['id']);
```

Note you need to reference the `$USER['antimatter']` variable ... i missed that in my original answer.

---

Essentially, your original code creates an SQL query that looks like this:

```
UPDATE [Users] SET `darkmatter` = `darkmatter` - [Price] WHERE `id` = [UserId]
```

Whereas it should look like this:

```
UPDATE [Users] SET `darkmatter` = [Cost - Price] WHERE `id` = [UserId]
```

Where the bits in [square brackets] are processed 'in code', eg variables like `$Price`, expressions like `$USER['antimatter'] - $price`.

To be honest, you should probably read up on SQL Injection Attacks ... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection

---

As Drew mentions, you are also treating your number as a string ... I have updated my answer to reflect that point (and also removed the semi-colon!)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe i understand somethings wrong or you just get my idea wrong, the things is that when i apply this code below  to my site it wont do anything

```
$GLOBALS['DATABASE']->query("UPDATE ".USERS." SET `darkmatter` = ". ($USER['antimatter'] - $price) ." WHERE `id` = ".$USER['id']);
```

and

```
$GLOBALS['DATABASE']->query("UPDATE ".USERS." SET `darkmatter` = `darkmatter` - '".$price."' WHERE `id` = ".$USER['id'].";");
```

This code i made for just testing its not the final code, i wanted to see if it works, but it do not change anythings in DB, it just print out message and thats all, there is no change in darkmatter. Only the GLOBAL below works

```
$GLOBALS['DATABASE']->query("UPDATE ".USERS." SET `darkbox` = '".$loli."', `antimatter` = `antimatter` - '".$price."' WHERE `id` = ".$USER['id'].";");
```

And i do not understand what i am doing wrong?